# sk-learn: Error of fit() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given in FeatureUnion

Tags: scikit-learn

I used sk-learn in python to fit models and transform input_data via the models.

I take **FeatureUnion** to combine **CountVectorizer** and **TfidfEmbeddingVectorizer.**

It is fine to use only CountVectorizer or only TfidfEmbeddingVectorizer, but if I combine two features by Feature Union, There is an error like this:

```
TypeError: fit() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

TfidfEmbeddingVectorizer class is like this:

```
class TfidfEmbeddingVectorizer(object):
   ...
    def fit(self, X):
            tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=lambda x: x)
            tfidf.fit(X)
            # if a word was never seen - it must be at least as infrequent
            # as any of the known words - so the default idf is the max of 
            # known idf's
            max_idf = max(tfidf.idf_)
            self.word2weight = defaultdict(
                lambda: max_idf,
                [(w, tfidf.idf_[i]) for w, i in tfidf.vocabulary_.items()])

            return self
```

And I used FeatureUnion like this:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(speech.train_data, size = 100)
w2v = dict(zip(model.wv.index2word, model.wv.syn0))

count = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda doc: doc, lowercase=False)
w2v_tfidf = TfidfEmbeddingVectorizer(w2v)
feature_union = FeatureUnion([('ngram', count),
                             ('tfidf', w2v_tfidf)])
feature_union.fit(speech.train_data)
```

I have seen a solution that Downgrading sk-learn version into 0.18.0 make it fine, But I can not downgrade sk-learn by this error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://andinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

Is there other solutions for using fit function of FeatureUnion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fit()` method of FeatureUnion takes `X`, and `y` as input as per the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html#sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.fit):

> fit(X, y=None)
>
> ```
> Fit all transformers using X.
> ```

Even though its default value is `None` but its still passed to the internal transformers. Its present there for compatibility reasons when used in a Pipeline.

Now talking about the internal transformers `fit()` method.

- [TfidfVectorizer's `fit()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit) has a signature:

> fit(raw_documents, y=None)
>
> ```
> Learn vocabulary and idf from training set.
> ```

As you can see, it also contains the `y` for the same reason even though does not use it anywhere.

- Your custom `TfidfEmbeddingVectorizer` fit() dont have the extra `y` parameter.

But the feature union will try to shove the `y` (with its `None` value) to it and hence the error. Just change the `fit` to :

```
def fit(self, X, y=None):
    ....
    ....
```